# Which dynamic linker to use on 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have a simple assembly language program that prints out hello world. It uses printf and exit functions from glibc, by dynamically linking to it.

If I use this version of linker:

```
ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux.so.2 -o helloworld-lib helloworld-lib.o -lc
```

Then I get this error, when I execute the executable file:
bash: ./helloworld-lib: Accessing a corrupted shared library

If I instead use:

```
ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o helloworld-lib helloworld-lib.o -lc
```

Then I'm getting Segmentation fault at the line where I call printf.

This is what my .s file looks like:

```
.section .data

helloworld:  
.ascii "hello world\n\0"

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:

 pushq $helloworld
 call printf

 pushq $0
 call exit
```

I'm using a 64 bit ubuntu system. Please clarify What am I doing wrong here. Thanks.

Edit:

If I replace the two lines:

```
pushq $helloworld
call printf
```

with:

```
    movl    $helloworld, %eax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
```

Then it works fine.

Comment: Morale: when writing assembly, pay attention to calling conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced code after `_start` by (using x86-64 calling convention):

```
mov $helloworld, %rdi
call printf

mov $0, %rdi    
call exit
```

Next, I used:

```
as helloworld.s -o helloworld.o
ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o helloworld helloworld.o -lc
```

And it works well.